# You don't have permission to access "http://www.carrefour.pk/" on this server.<p> Reference #18.451d2017.1615456534.6b4445

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, request

I'm trying to **scrape** carrefour website data through python. I've used scrappy, beautiful soup, selenium but nothing seems to work. I'm getting the error that you don't have the permission to access. Is there any way to **scrape** this website? The code is attached below, NEED HELP!

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession


session = HTMLSession()
 
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"}

resp = session.get("https://www.carrefour.pk/",headers=headers)

resp.html.render()

a=resp.html.html

print(a)
```

Comment: Maybe try blocking coockies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

think you are using the wrong headers. These headers work fine for me.
`headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Cafari/537.36'}`

Or full:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


# Block cookies
from http import cookiejar  # Python 2: import cookielib as cookiejar
class BlockAll(cookiejar.CookiePolicy):
    return_ok = set_ok = domain_return_ok = path_return_ok = lambda self, *args, **kwargs: False
    netscape = True
    rfc2965 = hide_cookie2 = False
    
s = requests.Session()
s.cookies.set_policy(BlockAll())


#Get URL
url = "https://www.carrefour.pk"
        
headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Cafari/537.36'}


r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

Comment: That solved my first problem. I've to scrap products data but my code is getting empty brackets in output. I don't know where I'm missing the point.

Comment: What do you want to scrape? You can filter by html tag, html class etc etc

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66582034/i-want-to-get-products-data-from-carrefouruae-com-when-im-inspecting-the-produ

Comment: please refer to the above mentioned question