# I want to get products data from carrefouruae.com. When I'm inspecting the products name and the div class, it's returning empty brackets

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, request

[website image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhIbg.jpg)
This is the code I'm using. The output is returning just a empty brackets instead of the data it has in the class.

```
        import requests 
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

    from http import cookiejar  
    class BlockAll(cookiejar.CookiePolicy):
        return_ok = set_ok = domain_return_ok = path_return_ok = lambda self, *args, **kwargs: False
        netscape = True
        rfc2965 = hide_cookie2 = False
        
    s = requests.Session()
    s.cookies.set_policy(BlockAll())
    url = "https://www.carrefouruae.com/mafuae/en/c/F1600000?currentPage=0&filter=&nextPageOffset=0&pageSize=60&sortBy=relevance"
            
    headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Cafari/537.36'}


    r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
    s=soup.find_all("div",{"class":"ltr-12fzzt2"})
    print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic websites like this one need Selenium to scrape data from them. BeautifulSoup is not for this. websites like these contain lot of Java script content. There is nothing wrong with your code.